# Unable to find JSP views in Spring MVC with Embedded Jetty 9

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I have a Spring MVC, upgrading the Embedded Jetty from Jetty 7 to Jetty 9.3.9 and Java 8. I rewrote the Embedded Jetty 9 class to support JSP for Jetty 9 referring examples [here](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/Main.java) and some helpful questions on SO, however still when I start the App server, I get

```
Problem accessing /webapp/WEB-INF/views/404.jsp
```

Whenever I try to access http://localhost:8080/webapp/index, I get 404 Not found, however, from the info logs I can see, the webapp is hitting My BaseController:

```
@Controller
public class BaseController{
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseController.class);
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
        Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        logger.info("Requested home page...");
        model.put("Welcome Page", "Welcome to home");
        return new ModelAndView("index", model);
}
```

My Project Hierarchy, I have two projects. Jetty-Startup to start the Jetty server to configure the server properties. Other project - webapp where all my web.xml, servlets, Controllers, JSP, JS, CSS etc resides.

Is there some configuration that I'm missing for JSP support? It would be very helpful anyone can figure out what I am missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm getting '404' while accesing the JSP pages which are in webapp >> src >> main >> webapp >> WEB-INF >> views directory. and my server is in different project - jetty-startup .Also, while starting the jetty, I see  `/webapp:main: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath`. Not sure if there is a configuration mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized form the Spring Debug logs that I had two servlets (appservlet & wsServlet) essentially mapping to same path in my web.xml

Mapped my wsServlet to different Url-pattern and was able to load the jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the JSP files path which needs to be configured properly in your `startServer()` as shown below:

```
context.addServlet(jspServletHolder(), "/WEB-INF/views/*.jsp");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried playing with the servlet path, unfortunately it didn't help. Still I'm getting 404.